# PC New installation using intel i3 9100f

Tags: graphics-card, cpu, motherboard, nvidia-graphics-card, desktop-computer

I need to build a PC and bought the parts from store. The parts I bought are as follows.

Processor - Intel i3 9100f (without integrated graphics)

Mother board - Gigabyte H310 S2H (LGA 1151) ( Have to update the BIOS inorder to use i3 9100f)

Graphics card - MSI 2GD3H LP DDR3 Graphics card (2GB memory)

RAM - 8GB

SSD - 120 GB

I need to install Ubuntu OS in the fresh SSD drive.
The steps I followed to build the PC  were.

After fixing all parts inside cpu cabinet, I updated the motherboard BIOS using Q flash plus method.

Since the i3 9100f don't  have integrated graphics I have to use some other external graphics card.

My doubt is how to install the Ubuntu OS in the fresh SSD after the BIOS update.

How to install graphics card drivers without the OS?.

Does the PC will start , even if it starts will I have any output in the monitor screen (Graphics card drivers were not installed yet).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should still get a display even if the drivers are not installed.  Have you actually ran into a problem or is this question trying to prevent a possible problem?

Comment: "Does the PC will start , even if it starts will I have any output in the monitor screen (Graphics card drivers were not installed yet)." - This sentence does not make sense, please edit it, and clarify it.  If you have not even attempted to install an OS, you should do that, before you edit your question.

Comment: I have asked this to prevent the possible problems. I am very new into building a PC . Since there is no onboard graphics description given in the motherboard product specification. I think i will not get any output in the monitor. That is why asked. I never tried to install the OS .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get a basic display even without the drivers installed. By not having the drivers installed, you'll probably be limited to a low resolution until you get the drivers installed.

As an example, for the Windows equivalent `Microsoft Basic Display` driver, uses a lower resolution until you can get your drivers installed. I'm not sure what the max resolution of the `Microsoft Basic Display` driver is.